# SignalR Client application exit

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I have a problem with signalr.
I wrote a service that send a file from web server to a desktop app for later work.
The problem is when I need to close the app, eve I call connection.stop, connection.dispose, hub.dispose the app will not close and I have to kill via task manager.

Can someone help me?

Edit:
Here is the connection initialization

```
this.Connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection(SisIdsEndPoint)
        {
            DeadlockErrorTimeout = new TimeSpan(deadlockDays, deadlockHours, deadlockMinutes)
        };
        _hub = Connection.CreateHubProxy("SisIdsRemoteClientHub");
        this.Connection.Error += ConnectionOnError;
        _hub.On<string, string, string, string, string, int>("GetData", GetData);
        _hub.On<string, string>("Error", AddLog);
        _hub.On("ConnectionOk", x => ConnectionOk(x));
        _hub.On("DisconnectOk", x => DisconnectOk(x));
        Connection.StateChanged += new Action<StateChange>(ConnChange);
        Connection.Closed += new Action(ConClosed);
        Connection.Start().Wait();
        _hub.Invoke("Hello", SisIdsApiKey, this.Utenti).Wait();
```

I have removed the log lines After that there is the "GetData" method wich is a simple function that accept some parameter and save the file And when I close the app I call

```
Connection.Stop();
Connection.Dispose();
Connection = null;
```

After that I tried Application.Restart() but the window freeze and debuggind the code it will freeze on Connection.Stop()

Comment: Are you sure that `app will not close` was caused by SignalR? would you provide us your code or at least sample code which produces same problem?

Comment: I'm sure, if I remove signalr everything is working, I will insert here some code

Comment: What do you do in ConClosed? Also you should not use .Wait() for async methods but await them. You are most likely deadlocking yourself...